# Host virtual Xampp

Tags: xampp, virtualhost, error404

Estoy configurando un host virtual en xampp modificando el archivo httpd-vhosts.conf

El problema es que cuando intento entrar a http://limsbp me sale el `error 404.`

Seguí los pasos de videos de youtube donde explican como hacerlo y no me funciona.

Alguno sabe que me puede estar faltando?

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:8080
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/limsbp/public"
    ServerName limsbp
</VirtualHost>
```

Y el archivo hosts

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       limsbp.localhost 
    127.0.0.1       limsbp


# Adobe Blocker
127.0.0.1 lmlicenses.wip4.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 lm.licenses.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 practivate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 lm.licenses.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 lmlicenses.wip4.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 ereg.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate.wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 3dns-3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 3dns-2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns-2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns-3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 ereg.wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate-sea.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip60.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate-sjc0.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 hl2rcv.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 lm.licenses.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 na2m-pr.licenses.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 na4r.services.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 ims-na1-prprod.adobelogin.com
127.0.0.1 na1r.services.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 hlrcv.stage.adobe.com
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si intentas acceder a `http://limsbp:8080`? Parece que estás asignándole el puerto 8080 al virtual host, pero al hacer sólo `http://limsbp` se irá al puerto 80 que parece no estar definido.

Comment: como dice @AlvaroMontoro en tu config solo tienes que escuchas el puerto 8080 , tienes dos opciones la que te dice Alvaro, o cambiar el archivo httpd a que escuche el 80, la segunda opcion puede ser mas dificil (skype usa el puerto 80 y te bloquea aveces el puerto u otra aplicacion)

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y ahora si funciona. El tema es que tenía entendido de que de esta forma me evitaba tener que colocar el puerto en la direccion. Existe alguna forma de que no tenga que ponerlo? Yo ya tengo configurado xampp para que escuche en el puerto 8080

Answer (score 0):

Los VirtualHost y seguramente el servidor lo tienes apuntando al puerto 8080, cuando visitas la URL http://limsbp sin especificar el puerto, el navegador pide por default el puerto 80, si agregaras el puerto a tu URL usando http://limsbp:8080 ahora si estarías pidiendo el VirtualHost que creaste.

Para el protocolo HTTP el puerto por default es el 80, hay puertos por default para otros protocolos como el https es el 443 o el FTP es el 21.

Para que tu servidor use el puerto 80, tendrías que cambiar en el archivo de httpd.conf la línea que traiga la directiva de **Listen 8080** por **Listen 80**, y en el archivo httpd-vhosts.conf que pegaste en la pregunta cambiar los 8080 por sólo 80, y ahora si podras usar tu URL http://limsbp y recibir el resultado esperado.